# Count forward and backward - Min max numbers

Tags: javascript, math

I have a min number and a max number

```
 t1Min = 70;
 t1Max = 1064;
 time = 1;
```

I need to simple count to a Max number (e.g. `1064`) and backward to the min number again (e.g.`70`). based on a given  number "seconds".
Starting with min Number (70).

**70**,71,73,74,75,76,77,...,1062,1063,**1064**,1063,1062,...75,74,73,72,71,**70**,71,72

Seconds could be 1,2,3,...45,46,47,..,2045,2046,2047

```
var time=1;
nums= new Array;
while(1){
    //time seconds 1,2,3,...45,46,47,
    t1 = t1Min+time;

    if(t1>t1Max){
        t1=t1Max-time;
    }
    time++;
    nums[time]=t1;
    }
```

But this doesn't work.
Need this for a timeline for a CSS3 Effect. Each Timeframe should increase the 3D Position

Comment: Need more info.  What do you mean by "count to a max number"?

Comment: @dazzafact can you add some more explaination

Comment: What does `time` have to do with the desired output?

Comment: Are you trying to print numbers to the console?  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: What is the final thing you're after? A value? An array of numbers. What does it mean to count based on a number of seconds?

Comment: need the numbers for an loop in CSS3 Effect

Comment: What's the CSS effect? This can probably be accomplished with CSS alone.

Comment: It is completely unclear what this question is about. I suggest to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, you can initialize an array of the length (your seconds) and then fill it in with `map()` or by using `Array.from()` (you could also just use a `for` loop`). Just alternate a counter between 1 and -1 as you go.

I've made it go between 10 and 20 for a length 30 to make the console readable:

```js
let min = 10
let max = 20
let length = 30
let counter = 1
let current = min
let arr = Array.from({length: length}, (_, i)=>{
    let ret = current
    current += counter
    if (current >= max || current <= min) counter *= -1
    return ret
})
console.log(arr.join(','))
```

You could also do it analytically, which is a little simpler (in a sense):

```js
let min = 5
let max = 12
let length = 20
let arr = Array.from({length: 40}, (_, i)=>{
    let m = Math.floor(i / (max - min))
    return m % 2
    ? max - (i - (max - min) * m )
    : min + (i - (max - min) * m )
    
})
console.log(arr.join(','))
```

Comment: it is possible to have a startposition getPosition(min,max,seekFrame), without any Loop?
because it always starts with the min Number

Comment: I don't understand @dazzafact. What is `seekFrame`? You're question makes it sound like you want to start with the min number. If that's not true, where should it start?